# Ubuntu 18.04 vs. 19.04 Printing

Tags: printing

After a recent update of 18.04 (minimal install), and setting up a new HP laserjet printer, I noticed the printer functions were not working correct: test page won't print, TBird can't see the printer, there were two versions of the same printer, and a phantom printer that doesn't seem to do anything.

But I also notice that 19.04 (full install) woks fine.  I suspect it's because the CUPS is newer.

I happen to like the minimal install of 18.04, so I'm thinking if I could install the 19.04 CUPS (in other words the newest CUPS) -- so that's my question: how can update the CUPS version?

I can't do with the normal apt commands because the return is that the newest version is installed (for 18.04.).

How do I install the CUPS from 19.04 to 18.04?

Comment: "I suspect it's because the CUPS is newer." Unlikely.  I would expect different setup between the 2 systems. Minimal install? Does that mean you manually installed the printer? How about copying the printer.conf from 19.04 to 18.04 to begin? That would copy over all of the settings :=)

Comment: Minimal install means that I selected "minimal install" from the Ubuntu 18.04 installer.  CUPS was installed automatically. In both cases the printer was discovered automatically, nothing done on my part.  "printer.conf" appears to be a binary file, and it appears that I cannot copy it.

Comment: Update: First, this is for HP PRINTERS. I solved the problem by using the setting function, search for printers, but added the printer IP.  For some reason there are about 1/2 dozen entries for printers, even though there is only one physical printer in my office.  But the trick is to select the one that has the correct ip listed, and is JETDIRECT.  Select the jetdirect printer, enter Hewlett-Packard, select the appropriate driver and it should work. I recalled the JetDirect software from way back, so I figured it would work. Best of luck.

Comment: @libernet if this solved your problem please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

First, this is for HP PRINTERS. I solved the problem by using the setting function, search for printers, but added the printer IP. For some reason there are about 1/2 dozen entries for printers, even though there is only one physical printer in my office. But the trick is to select the one that has the correct ip listed, and is JETDIRECT. Select the jetdirect printer, enter Hewlett-Packard, select the appropriate driver and it should work. I recalled the JetDirect software from way back, so I figured it would work. Best of luck.